# Multi-NodeHadoop: NameNode and DataNode not working

Tags: hadoop

I am new student on Hadoop clusters, and I built a multi-node in the lab
But I cannot start NameNode or DataNode.

After I execute `start-all.sh` and jps: only shows jobtracker, tasktracker, secondenamenode, jps on Master. But slaves works good with datanode and tasktracker

And when I execute `stop-all.sh`:
it should shows: No tasttracker to stop, but it did show in jps

And this is the log file about NameNode:

> 1.Cannot access storage directory /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name
>   2.ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server![enter image description here][2].namenode.FSNamesystem: FSNamesystem initialization failed.
>   3.org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
>   4.org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.

And I did try the `namenode -format`, yet it doesn't work.
Could somebody show me the way, and tell me why this happens?
Lots of thanks ahead.
PS: I am using hadoop1.0.3 + java1.7.0_51

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you did not give permissions to data dir of `tmp.data.dir`.
Try bellow command to give permissions and try your `start-all.sh` once.

```
sudo chown $USER /(DIR NAME).
```

And try this command:

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

Comment: This is the right thinking and solution. I realized that on My Master Node, I created the /tmp without chown it to the right user. Thank you for your excellent help!